# Want to edit mezzanine footer

Tags: django, footer, mezzanine

I want to edit the Mezzanine footer. The one which contains powered by Django and Mezzanine. I'm new to this. How should I go about editing it ?

Comment: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#where-are-all-the-templates-i-can-modify

Answer (score 2):

You will need to override the template displaying the footer(`base.html`).

Start by collecting all the templates into a single `/templates` folder:

```
python manage.py collecttemplates
```

You will also need an app to hold your overridden templates, I tend to call
this `core`:

```
python manage.py startapp core
```

Make sure to add this to the top of your `INSTALLED_APPS`, before any mezzanine
modules.

Then copy or move the templates to override into the `core` app:

```
mkdir core/templates
mv templates/base.html core/templates/
```

Then edit the template in `core/templates` however you like.

Comment: Related documentation: Django tutorial step 1 [Project creation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models) and Mezzanine FAQ [Where are all the templates I can modify?](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#templates)